# How to test values of variables using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am using Mockito for testing, I am able to mock methods and verify if any exceptions are thrown, how can I assert value of a variable from my test class

```
@Service
public class TaskImpl implements Task {

@Autowired
private Utils utils;

@Override
public void doSomeTask(String input, String oldId, String newId) {

    Long id = utils.getId(input);
    if(id == null) {
        throw new CustomException(CustomExceptionCode.ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
    }

    String code = utils.findCode(id, newId);
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
        throw new CustomException(CustomExceptionCode.NO_CODE_FOR_ID);
    }

    // some more stuff
    }
}


@PowerMockIgnore("org.jacoco.agent.rt.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TaskImpl.class})
public class TaskImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private final TaskImpl taskImpl = PowerMockito.spy(new TaskImpl());

    @Mock
    private Util util;

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void doSomeTaskThrowsException() {
        when(util.getId(anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        exception.expect(CustomException.class);
        taskImpl.doSomeTask(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomeTastCodeSuccess()  {
        when(util.getId(anyString())).thenReturn(1L);
        taskImpl.doSomeTask(anyString(), anyString(), "new_id");
        // I want to check here how to check {code} value is actually what I am expecting
        // Not only string but I want to check other types too
    }
}
```

so in my second test I want to `Assert.assertEquals("expected", code);`

one way I could do is

`String code = util.findCode(id, newId);`

and then check

`Assert.assertEquals("expected", code);`

is that correct or is there any other way to check variables.

Comment: Given that you've mocked out util(s), what would be the point of making assertions on what it returns?!

Comment: my approach looks redundant to me, doing same calls in original class and test class as well. so I want to use value obtained in original class and assert, reducing number of calls eventually

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah that worked for other clases, but if util is an interface extending `JpaRepository` with hibernate definitions to DB

Comment: ... *what* worked? As far as we can tell, you've mocked out Util(s) and are testing *TaskImpl*. *Don't test mocks*, use them to test the production code they're supposed to be interacting with.